# How to convert a form field to Vavr Option in Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, option-type, vavr

I have a class `Outcome`, one of whose fields is an instance of `Schema`. But because the latter might be null, I have defined `Outcome`'s `getSchema()` to return the value wrapped in Vavr's `Option`. In my Spring Boot 2 application the controller method that handles updating `Outcome`s has a parameter `@Valid Outcome outcome`. However when attempting to populate this parameter from the form data Spring's conversion service flags up the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'io.vavr.control.Option' for property 'schema': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

That is, it has been unable to map a string identifier such as '1234' to the existing `Schema` instance with that `Long` identifier and then set the `Outcome` instance's `schema` field to that. This is despite the fact that in my `WebMvcConfigurer` class I have added to Spring's conversion service Spring Data's `QueryExecutionConverters`, which are claimed to handle converting Vavr `Optional`:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConfigurableConversionService;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService;
import org.springframework.data.repository.util.QueryExecutionConverters;
...

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean(name="conversionService")
    public ConversionService getConversionService() {
        ConfigurableConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
        QueryExecutionConverters.registerConvertersIn(conversionService);
        System.out.println("Registered QueryExecutionConverters");
        return conversionService;
    }

    ...
```

If I change `Outcome`'s `getSchema()` to return Java 8's `Optional<Schema>` instead then the schema field **is** successfully set for the `Outcome` instance passed to my controller method.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Naive question: Have you added the vavr-jackson module?

Comment: @jdebon Yes, I've added the vavr-jackson module as a dependency.

Comment: It's not enough: you also need to provide a Spring bean of type Module which returns a new VavrModule.